# how to check if a user has not logged in for x number of days and then Disable a user in a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Need to write a process in place to see if the user is logged in or not for x number of days and then disable the user in a table

Comment: This is not a question, it is an explanation of a task.

Comment: Try reading this, and then edit your question:   https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0):

It'll be SQL something like

```
UPDATE [User-table] 
      SET Active = 0 
      WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM [Activity-log] A
                                 WHERE
                                   A.UserId = [User-table].UserId
                                   AND
                                   A.LogTime >= DATEADD(day, -1 * @X, getdate())
                       )
```

Comment: Thank you Cato. So, this implies that we need to create an Activity log table that tracks on a daily basis of all the users who are logged in

Comment: you could also maintain a 'latest log in' date for each user, then there would be less data.  Each time a user logs in successfully, the field is populated with date and time of log in - assuming he will not be active for x days continuously, you'd need to watch out for that, he might use the system for 50 days, log-out, then get disabled for not logging in.  But, yes, you will need to keep records to do this

Comment: That's very helpful information Cato. I do have a table of users. So, if I were to create a Activity_log table with certain attributes, I need to write a logic in place as to how to populate this table first based on who is logged in. Any suggestions as to how we could trace the steps of user logging activity

Comment: you'd update or write a record at each time of log in, or at each time of any action